# how to serve the CSS as a result of a controller action in yii1

Tags: css, yii

i want users to have a feature where users can select color, font ,font size, font color etc. below is my theme.php file which is a php file containing css.

```
 <?php

    header('Content-type:text/css');

    ?>
    <style>
    .btn-default.btn-icon.btn-lg i{padding:10px 10px;font-size:<?php echo $size; ?>;line-height:1.33;border-radius:3px;color:<?php echo $color; ?>}
    </style>
```

How could i get to call this, so that values of $color, $size can be taken from database. I have a table called templates with fields parameter name and parameter value. I want to use values from that table.

Comment: is theme.php your view file or layout file?

Comment: theme.php was a css file which i turned into a php file so that i can change values of different elements in css.

Comment: You can use like this $this->render("theme",array("size"=>30)); can you let me know where you have added this file ?

Comment: i got it working. i put $this->renderPartial(/theme) inside the layout and placed the theme.php file inside view

Comment: Great. Answer your question and accept it. So Someone get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller or view file, you can add:

```
$css = <<<EOF
.btn-default.btn-icon.btn-lg i{padding:10px 10px;font-size:{$size};line-height:1.33;border-radius:3px;color:{$color}}
EOF;

Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCss('your-color', $css);
```